# Viewpager wrong OnItemClick position

Tags: android, firebase, android-viewpager, firebase-realtime-database

My app has a fragment that host a nested viewPager (One fragment added every time)  all views are linked to the same layout.

Each fragment has a fixed button + recylerview that retrieve its data from firebase adapter.

When I click on the button, it show the correct viewPager position. But if I click on the listview item (viewHolder) it show the next pre-loaded position in the viewPager.

here's the viewpager and the pager adapter of the root fragment

**Explore.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);
    array = controller.SELECTED_CATEGORIES;
    viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.categories_tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return root;
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return controller.SELECTED_CATEGORIES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return CategoriesFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
        return controller.SELECTED_CATEGORIES[position];
    }
}
```

**CategoriesFragment.java**

```
static CategoriesFragment newInstance(int num) {
    CategoriesFragment f = new CategoriesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);
    initialize();
    listCategoriesFeed = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listCategoriesFeeds);
    categoriesFeedAdapter = new CategoriesFeedAdapter(CategoriesFeedItem.class, R.layout.categoriesfeed_list_item, CategoriesFeedHolder.class, myref);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    listCategoriesFeed.setLayoutManager(llm);
    listCategoriesFeed.setAdapter(categoriesFeedAdapter);

    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    //Holder itemClickListener
    CategoriesFeedHolder.registerOnItemClickListener(this);

    //TextView onclick listener
    View tv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("position",mNum + "");
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
super.onItemClick(view, position);
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.firstId:  
            Log.e("position",mNum+ "");
            break;
        case R.id.secondId:
            secondAction....
            .....
            .....
            .....
            break;
    }
}


private void initialize() {
    controller.showProgressDialog();
    list = controller.getIniCategoriesDetailsList();
    list.clear();
    controller.categoriesDetailsList.put(controller.SELECTED_CATEGORIES[mNum],list);
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("firebase-path/" + controller.SELECTED_CATEGORIES[mNum]);
    myref = reference.orderByChild("order-by").limitToFirst(i);
    myref.addChildEventListener(this);
}
```

**CategoriesFeedHolder.java**

```
private CategoriesFeedItem model;
private final ImageView mImage;

private static OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public CategoriesFeedHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = itemView.getContext();

    mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_image);
    mImage.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public static void registerOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    CategoriesFeedHolder.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public void setModel(CategoriesFeedItem model) {
    this.model = model;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: you should really add some code.. otherwise it will be very difficult to help you

Comment: Why are you checking id in ItemClickListener with R.id.firstId? here you have to operate with position variable. and why onItemClickListener inside holder class is static?

Comment: OnItemClick is for the viewHolder, the viewaholder has 5 buttons, each of them has its own action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the viewholder class, there was no data binding inside it. So when i clicked on any item inside the viewholder, it performed the action on the current adapter's data (preloaded data).

the viewholder class should be something like this:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    share = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
}

public void bindToPost(Post post, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    share.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
```